# Model inference using pyspark pandas_udf runs twice

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyspark, amazon-emr

Using python 3.7, pyspark 2.4.7 on emr 5.33.1.

From trained keras model on pandas I'm trying to do distributed inference using pyspark.

I have inference function wrapped with pandas_udf.

```
@pandas_udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def run_inf(*cols):
    print("run inf initiated")
    X= pd.concat(cols, axis=1)
    model.set_weights(bc_model_weight.value)
    predictions = model.predict(X)
    return pd.Series(predictions.reshape(-1))
```

Running this function prints the print statement twice...

```
bc_model_weight = sc.braodcast(model.get_weights())
pdf = spark.read.parquet(path_to_file).select(*all_cols)
feature_cols = [f for f in all_cols if f.endswith("feature")]
pdf = pdf.withColumn('pred', run_inf(*feature_cols))
pdf.show()
```

outputs:

```
run inf initiated
    
tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled

run inf initiated

|...|...|score|
|...|...|0.3|
|...|...|0.11|
|...|...|0.23|
```

[EDIT]
After searching, this is a problem when doing star expansion.
from https://towardsdatascience.com/pyspark-udfs-and-star-expansion-b50f501dcb7b?gi=942293c18125 I've learned that we could use explain() method to see physical plan.

When I run exaplain() before .show() it contains only one run_inf(). So I'm gueesing it is being ran once once... But then why is it printing the print statement inside it twice?

[EDIT 2]
Thanks to @AzharKhan I've printed out how many executors are being used by spark by following code:

```
sc = spark._jsc.sc()
used_executor_driver = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus().keys()
print(used_executor_driver)
```

which prints only one IP address.
From this I can conclude that It has one executor?

Also I've tried printing `socket.gethostname()` inside pandas_udf and this prints same name.

Comment: I could not find any documentation link to support this comment, so I may be wrong here: The serialisation from pyspark to pandas series/dataframe occurs at each executor node for each partition. You are possibly running inference on multiple nodes. Which logs are you looking at? Just the driver logs or executor logs?

Comment: Yeah that could be it, how to check number lf executors? It is error log (shown in console) I get when I run python script.